# Is there a way to add multiple conditions while doing the product in Maple?

Tags: maple

**Note**: I've searched for the answer to this already but I can't find what I need. I may have overlooked something or maybe this is referred to in a different way. I'll delete this if someone points out that it is a duplicate, please let me know.

**Question**: How can I add multiple conditions to the `product` or `mul` in Maple?

**Example**: I am trying to re-create the following, I cannot seem to find a way to add both `r != k` and `r=1` as parameters.

[image]

I've gone over the documentation of the [product](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=product) command and maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional products can be achieved using sets for index range (in the example below R is a set or can be a list, but set is better in this case since it's easier to remove its members), but that set must not have unknown parameters (so it's a *numeric* range).
For example:

```
[> j:=6: k:=3:
   R:={seq(s, s in {seq(s,s=1..j-1)} minus {k})};
   mul(r/(r-k), r in R);
```

The output will be:

```
        R := {1, 2, 4, 5}
               10
```

You can do it without additional variable R too:

```
[> mul(r/(r-k), r in {seq(s, s in {seq(s,s=1..j-1)} minus {k})});
```

A comparison of **mul** and **product**:

1. **mul** works only for numeric ranges and there should be no *infinity* involved, it also works for **r in R** case.
2. **product** can work with *symbolic* ranges, also range can have *infinity*, but it doesn't work for **r in R** case.
3. **product** is more powerful, but **mul** is much faster, so for numeric ranges **mul** should be always used instead (similarly **add** should used instead of **sum** for numeric ranges).

You can use **mul** with parameters too, but the range should be numeric (R is defined above):

```
[> mul((a+r)/(b+r-k), r in R);
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the formula that you showed in your question to be displayed symbolically as you have, I don't have any idea at the moment in Maple. As you may have seen in the help page of `product`, it only accepts ranges of the form `idx=n..m` or `idx=n` and that's it. But if you have values in `k` and `j` and want to receive the result of your formula, you can use `mul`, not `product`. As @Robai did a comparison in her answer between `mul` and `product`, the important thing here is that `product` does not support its second argument (the range) to be in the form `idx in set`, no "`in`" for `product` and that means you can not use `product` for your case even with the formulation given in @Robai's answer.

Now for `mul`, other than the set-minus idea of @Robai's answer. Here is another approach (you can read more about it in another answer I posted for another question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498377/6195473).

```
j := 5:
k := 2:
idxs := select( x -> x <> k, [ seq( r, r = 1..j-1 ) ] );
(k/(j-k)) * mul( r/(r-k), r in idxs );
```

Here is a screenshot from the output.
[image]